# SQLite. What is better: check if table exists and then create it (or not) or "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I have implemented simple cache stored in `SQLite` database. For one client there is one table in database. I want to automaticaly create this table if it not exists. What will be better sollution, checking if table exists using query: `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='table_name';` or using `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (...)`? I have to do this every time I need cache, so I wonder which way will be more efficient and more correct.

I'm using `PDO`, so maybe there is some cleverer way to do this?

**Solution:**
Use [`PDO::errorCode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php) to find if table doesn't exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with `create table if not exists` because it'll be compatible with other databases should you need it one day (in case of sqlite particularly it's unlikely you'll switch, but still).

Also if you check `sqlite_master` and don't find your table there you need to send another query to create it. With `create table` you're only sending one query, although with table structure defined in it, but if your table structure is not hard to generate or is predefined, you'll have no problems supplying it every time with `create table`.

It also depends on how likely is it for your tables not to exist. If that is not very likely and you just want your app to be safe and self-maintaining you can just assume they exist and process exceptions to create table when queries assuming they exist fail.

Comment: It can happen, but I don't know when, how often or even if it happen. Table structure is trivial, just 3 columns (varchar, text, integer). Unfortunately if table doesn't exists it throws general error, so I don't know if it's error caused by syntax or table absence.

Comment: You can check `PDO::errorCode()` for `SQLSTATE` code of the occurred error - for table that doesn't exists it's '42S02'. Look at the example given at http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php. If you still prefer checking every time in advance, I'd go with the `create table` option for the reasons stated above.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about it. It's perhaps the best and cleanest solution.

Comment: You're welcome. If that answers your question can you please mark the answer as "accepted"?